# Is it possible to know how many beans are in the pool in a given moment?

Tags: ejb, java-ee-6

In a running java ee application (in jboss 6, if that matters), is it possible to know how many beans of a given class are on the pool at a moment?

Answer (score 1):

Not out-of-box, but you can think about some counter field for singleton, as soon as static fields aren't welcome in this environment.
Such counter could be:

- incremented in @PostConstruct annotated method of the bean you are interested in
- decremented in @PreDestroy annotated method

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use for example VisualVM MBeans Browser:

https://visualvm.github.io/plugins.html:

[image: MBeans Browser - pool statistics]